# How to Execute login test case for multiple data using selenium Nunit C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I want to execute login test case with Different set of Data. i have 27 usernames and passwords to execute. Please suggest me the ans

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Then read [ask] and take a few minutes to add some details to your question, especially an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You could have 27 different test cases if the users and/or passwords are different enough to merit a separate test case.

For example:

- usernames containing special characters, spaces, non-ASCII characters, ...
- passwords not satisfying certain criteria, such as password strength, length, ...

If however you are certain you want to execute everything in the same test case, you can just iterate through all of them and assert that logging in succeeded.

You didn't provide any code, so I don't know the structure of your existing test cases, and the pages you already implemented using Selenium, but here's some pseudo code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace AutomatedTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class LoginTests
    {
        public static string BaseUrl = "http://www.example.com";
        public static string LoggedInPageTitle = "Dashboard Page";

        Dictionary<string, string> username_password = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"JonhJohnson", "pwD123"},
                {"DanielSmith", "pass!@#"},
                {"RichardSummers", "secret_word"}
            };


        [TestCase]
        public void CanLoginWithAllUsers()
        {
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseUrl);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in username_password)
            {
                TestContext.WriteLine("Attempting ti sign in with user: {0}, who's password is: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);

                var usernameField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Username"));
                usernameField.SendKeys(pair.Key);

                var passwordField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
                passwordField.SendKeys(pair.Value);

                var loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Log in"));
                loginButton.Click();

                Assert.That(driver.Title == LoggedInPageTitle, "Failed to login with user {0}", pair.Key);

                var signOutButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Sign out"));
                signOutButton.Click();
            }

            driver.Quit();

        }

    }
}
```

(edit your question and paste what you already have, and what you've tried, so the answer is closer to what you already use)

Variable values should be picked up from somewhere else (not hard-coded in the tests) in my opinion, and the way username/password is presented here (as a Dictionary) is just a dummy example. There's a bunch of things here that are not ideal, or could be better, but this is just to give you an idea on how to proceed.